# GraphQl useQuery loading state always returns false

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to use useQuery to fetch posts data from my graphQL server and it works fine after it's first compiled but then when I refresh it fails to get the data and erros out from useQuery because the loading state always returns false.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPosts' of undefined
Home
src/pages/Home.jsx:10
7 | function Home() {
8 |   const {
9 |     loading,
> 10 |     data: { getPosts: posts }
11 |   } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
12 |   console.log(loading)
13 |
```

``

```
function Home() {
 const {
 loading,
 data: { getPosts: posts }
 } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
  console.log(loading)
```

``

```
{loading ? (
      <h1>Loading posts..</h1>
    ) : (
      <Transition.Group>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((post) => (
            <Grid.Column key={post.id} style={{ marginBottom: 20 }}>
              <PostCard post={post} />
            </Grid.Column>
          ))}
      </Transition.Group>
    )}
```